# Weighted Probability

Tags: formula

I want to create a formula for Weighted probability for Annual Recurring Revenue (ARR) within salesforce.

Unweighted I can simply do: `Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * PROBABILITY`

I believe I need an IF statement though where anything with probability (0% should go to 100% and anything 60% should go to 70% weighted.

I am attempting:

```
IF(PROBABILITY >= 90, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 1, 
IF(PROBABILITY >= 60, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 0.7))
```

but I am getting ERROR when encoding row-level formula:

> Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2

What should I do?

Comment: What is the scenerio if the probability is less than 60%?

Comment: Your requirements are a bit unclear. Please try to **[edit]** your post to clarify them. Please note the function syntax is `IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. The error tells you exactly what you are doing wrong in a micro sense.

Answer (score 2):

When writing nested IFs in a Formula Field, you have to be ensure a few things. Readability and correct number of `(` and `)`.

Also you are missing an additional "ELSE" parameter in a number form like 0 or Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c . So you have to write it like :

```
IF(PROBABILITY >= 90, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 1, 
  IF(PROBABILITY >= 60, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 0.7, <number>))
```

Comment: Thank you. this formula eventually worked: IF(PROBABILITY >= 90, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 1, 
IF(PROBABILITY >= 60, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 0.7, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c*PROBABILITY)).

Comment: How do I make these resulting numbers into currency with a $ in front of it instead of just the stand alone number?

Comment: @brick612 Have your formula return the `Currency` type instead of using the `Number` type. This is something you select as you first create the formula field. It can also be edited (the return type picklist appears above space where you write the formula when you edit the formula field).

Answer (score 2):

The [official help page on Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.customize_functions.htm) is a good reference (even if the navigation is trash).

As Adrian mentioned in the comments (and compski in their answer), you're missing what should happen in the case where Probability < 60. The `IF()` function *must always have all 3 parts*.

Beyond that though, it's generally a good idea to keep repetition to a minimum in formulas. Instead of doing the calculation in the `IF()` function, you could re-organize your formula so that the `IF()` function only tells you what weighting to use. It might not matter too much in this particular instance, but it's good to maintain discipline since we are limited in the number of characters a formula can be (as well as the number of bytes the formula compiles to, which is almost guaranteed to be different and higher).

```
Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c *
IF(
    Probability >= 90,
    1,
    IF(
        Probability >= 60,
        0.7,
        0.5 /* placeholder value for < 60%, to be determined by you */
    )
)
```

Less typing is generally better.
Also, indenting formulas as you would if it were code (as I have done here) helps to make them easier to read and manage (it's very easy to get lost in the sea of parenthesis if you don't). The indentations won't be shown when you simply view the formula through the UI, but they are preserved and shown when you go to edit a formula in the UI.

Comment: So apparently I needed to make 90 and 60 a decimal also: IF(PROBABILITY >= 0.90, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 1, 
IF(PROBABILITY >= 0.60, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * 0.7, Opportunity.Incremental_ARR__c * PROBABILITY))